# Track Online Users in Identity Server 4 and Asp Core Client

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I have an app set up with the above authentication framework (Identity Server and Asp Identity), how can i go about tracking online users.

Advice or directions please.

Comment: Tracking in what sense? Auditing what they do on the site?

Comment: @Matt Tracking if they are logged in , if they are online

Comment: You cannot actually see if someone is online, unless you add javascript that sends a heart-beat. You can register the time a user accessed the resource. By simply adding some middleware (after the user is authorized) where you update the users 'LastVisit' timestamp. You can clear the field if a user logs out.

Comment: SignalR, it isn't available in .NET Core yet, but will soon

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at the eventing functionality to do this, the answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38770098/identity-server-3-logging-client-id-for-reporting) shows the basic approach.